# Нужно ли двоеточие? (1)

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Нужно ли двоеточие после слова "подумал"?

**Витя подумал(?) что ножик стоит свободы Снегиря...**

Answer (score 2):

Ставим запятую: **Витя подумал, что ножик стоит свободы Снегиря....**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, союз ЧТО (косвенная речь). А  двоеточие ставится в бессоюзном предложении или при оформлении прямой речи.